# Inheritance Using Button

Tags: java, swing, oop, methods

I have an assignment where I have two JPanels and I need to be able to push button1 in jpanel1 and get information to change on button2 of jpanel2. I've been working on the problem for a few days and no matter what I try I get stuck.

My idea is that I need a method to convert the button in jpanel2 to a button in jpanel that changes once the button in jpanel1 is pushed. Thing is that I can't figure out how to get a method to work with a button.

Here's what I have so far.

MyJPanel:

```
public class myJPanel extends JPanel { 
    public myJPanel(){           
        super();
        JButton j2 = new JButton("..");

        setBackground(Color.gray);      
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        myJPanel1 p1 = new myJPanel1(JButton(j2)); // thought something

        //like this would work to pass jpanel2 to jpanel1 using
        //myjpanel as the common class
        add(p1,"North");
        myJPanel2 p2 = new myJPanel2(j2);
        add(p2,"Center");                               
    }
}
```

panel1

```
public class myJPanel1 extends JPanel implements ActionListener {   
    student st1 = new student("Fred","Fonseca",44);

    JButton j = new JButton(st1.getInfo());
    JButton b1 = new JButton("..");


    public myJPanel1(JButton j2) {
        super();
        setBackground(Color.yellow);

        // the whatsUp of this student has to shown in the other panel
        j.addActionListener(this); 
        add(j);
        add(b1);             
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

        Object obj = event.getSource();
        //=====================================

        if (obj == j){            
            j2.setText(st1.whatsUp()); // Output on JButton in JPanel2 
            b1.setText(st1.whatsUp());
        }      
    }
}
```

jpanel2

```
public class myJPanel2 extends JPanel {
    JButton j1 = new JButton("When the user clicks on the button in the UPPER panel" );

    public void setButton(JButton j2){
        j1 = j2; // shouldn't this pass convert the information between the classes?
    }

    public myJPanel2(JButton j1){
        super();
        setBackground(Color.pink);
        setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));
        add(j1);
        j1.setText("");
    }    
}
```

Comment: A JButton cannot be converted to a JPanel, you can hide and show as needed, you can have a container that renders what you need and you can use any other JComponent behavior for them.

Comment: Can you break it up a little bit? I cannot understand what exactly do you need.. if you can isolate the issue that would be better.

Comment: I'm not trying to convert a JButton to a JPanel. I need a Jbutton that is shared by JPanel1 and jpanel2. That way when I click jbutton1 in jpanel1 then jbutton2 in jpanel2 changes.

Comment: Yo should accept answers because that is the way to say thanks to the folks that take time of their own to help you. This goes for all the question you haven't accepted

Comment: @omainegra: No need to rush him to accept an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help you:

MyJPanel1

```
public class MyJPanel1 extends JPanel { 

    private JButton localButton;

    private JButton remoteButton;

    public MyJPanel1(JButton localButton, JButton remoteButton){
        this.localButton= localButton;
        this.remoteButton = remoteButton;

        //add localButton to the JPanel

        //you can do, whatever you want with the remote (other panel) button.
        this.localButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                this.remoteButton.setText("I can reach you Button2"); 
            }
        }); 
    }
}
```

MyJPanel2

```
public class MyJPanel2 extends JPanel { 

    private JButton localButton;

    private JButton remoteButton;

    public MyJPanel2(JButton localButton, JButton remoteButton){
        this.localButton = localButton;
        this.remoteButton = remoteButton;

        //add localButton to the JPanel

        //you can do, whatever you want with the remote (other panel) button.
        this.localButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                this.remoteButton.setText("I can reach you Button1"); 
            }
        }); 
    }
}
```

And your main Panel.

```
public class MyJPanel extends JPanel { 
    public myJPanel(){           
        super();

        JButton j1 = new JButton("Button1");
        JButton j2 = new JButton("Button2");

        //Notice the order of parameters here (Local for one is remote for the other)
        MyJPanel1 p1 = new MyJPanel1(j1, j2);
        MyJPanel2 p2 = new MyJPanel2(j2, j1);

        setBackground(Color.gray);      
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        add(p1,"North");    
        add(p2,"Center");                               
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but I think that you're getting bad advice since folks are telling you to make a field public to allow it to be accessed by another class. Yes this will work, but it in the long term it can be a dangerous thing to do since it allows unwanted and unknown side effects to occur to your class. Better to protect your fields by making the private, and only allowing outside classes the ability to change the states that you want to be changed and nothing else by giving your class public methods to do this.  For instance if you had a class like so:

```
// you'll need imports here

public class MyPanel extends JPanel {
   private JButton button = new JButton();

   public MyPanel(String name) {
      add(button);
      setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(name));
   }

   public void setButtonAction(Action action) {
      button.setAction(action);
   }

   public void setButtonText(String text) {
      button.setText(text);
   }
}
```

Then an outside class can set the Action (consider this a more robust ActionListener) of the button as well as its text.

You could then use this class like so:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ChangingButtons extends JPanel {

   public ChangingButtons() {
      final MyPanel panel1 = new MyPanel("Panel 1");
      final MyPanel panel2 = new MyPanel("Panel 2");
      panel2.setButtonText("Button 2");

      panel1.setButtonAction(new AbstractAction("Button 1") {
         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            panel2.setButtonText("Foobar!");
         }
      });

      add(panel1);
      add(panel2);
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("ChangingButtons");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(new ChangingButtons());
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Note that even this example exposes too much since my classes needlessly extend JPanel, but this seems like a requirement of your assignment and so I left it in place.

As an aside, your question title, "Inheritance using button" may be a bit misleading since your problem isn't about inheritance, you are not extending your JButtons, but rather about inter-class communication and Object-Oriented Programming fundamentals.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're getting into a mess here - if you really want to access these buttons in this manner then why not make them public within the class.

that way you can refer to the buttons on the panels directly see : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html for details.

Comment: No, please don't have him break encapsulation. Much better to give the class that needs to change its state a public method that the other class can call.